# PHP uploading multiple images to a folder and syncrhonizing mysql

Tags: php

i dont know why this code is not working

it limits it self to 2 uploads
if i choose four images it will only upload 2 if i choose 2 it uploads 1
 is there a number of times that it runs and im not aware of

```
<?php
    echo 'hey';
?>  
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <ul>

            <li>
                Year:<br>
                <input type="text" name="year">
            </li>
            <li>
                Make:<br>
            <input type="text" name="make">
            </li>

            <li>
                Image1: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /></li>
                <li>Image2: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /></li>
                <li>Image3: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /></li>
                <li>Image4: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /></li>


            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>


        </ul>

    </form>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$success = 0;
$fail = 0;

$uploads_dir = 'images';
$count = rand(5, 7000);
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
        $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
        if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/",$ext)){
            $newfile = "$uploads_dir/picture".str_pad($count,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).".".$ext;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
                $success++;
            }else{
                echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
                $fail++;
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }
}
echo "<br> Number of files Uploaded:".$success;
echo "<br> Number of files Failed:".$fail;
```

Comment: Create a list of the names generated by your script to debug it, maybe you are overwriting some files

Comment: put $count = rand(5, 7000); inside of **foreach**.

like

...

$uploads_dir = 'images';

foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {

$count = rand(5, 7000);

...